# Column Differences in Python Pivot-Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas pivot_table that aggregates 2 data sets in 2 columns across several rows.  I would like to add another column that is the difference between the aggregated values in the two existing columns by row.  Is there a way to implement this directly in the pivot_table() call?  I know that the returned pivot is a dataframe so I can calculate it through other means, but just curious if there is a more efficient way.

Simple example of my data:

```
  Set     Type   Val
  S1       A     1
  S1       B     2
  S1       B     3
  S2       A     4
  S2       B     5
  S2       C     6
```

Using the following code where data is my df

```
piv=pivot_table(data,'Val',rows='Type',cols='Set',aggfunc=sum,fill_value=0.0)
```

I get the below

```
    S1  S2
A   1   4
B   5   5
C   0   6
```

I would like the output to be

```
    S1  S2 Diff
A   1   4   3
B   5   5   0
C   0   6   6
```

or just

```
   Diff
A   3
B   0
C   6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy. Dataframes (and matrices in general) make it easy to operate on multiple elements at one go.

Define the function you want to apply.

```
>>> def abs_diff(x, y):
>>>     return abs(x - y)
```

Then, apply it.

```
>>> df['Diff'] = abs_diff(df['S1'], df['S2'])

>>> df

   S1  S2  Diff
A   1   4     3
B   5   5     0
C   0   6     6
```

And of course, if you just want to render the specific column:-

```
>>> df['Diff']

A    3
B    0
C    6
Name: Diff
```

(`>>>` is the python shell prompt of course)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar.  Was wondering if the pandas pivot had any similar built in functionality.

Comment: @Calvin thats not the answer we were looking for. MattB specified that he is looking for something within pivot table like aggfunc.